# Increase volume of /home partition with unallocated space

Tags: gparted, debian

I have been trying to resize my `/home` partition (`/dev/sda5`) with the unallocated space (325 GiB), I tried `gparted` but it seems that I can't add the unallocated space.

[image: gparted]

The `fdisk -l` output:

[image: fdisk]

Can someone help me?

Comment: You can't do it that way and moving it to the left is a baaaaddd idea. Best suggestion: Keep it the way it is. Make a new partition for storage in the free space. Only 20GB for /? You might want to back everything up and reinstall to get the sizes you want.

Comment: can you add to your question the output of `sudo fdisk -l` that is a lower cased L not an upper cased i.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to move the partition, but this cannot be performed from within a running system. To do this, boot from Ubuntu Live or GParted Live media. Unmount the mounted partitions. Click **`Resize`** on `sda5`. Drag the partition towards left (unallocated space is in left side!). This takes a lot of time because it is moving all data to a new location. Reboot to your main operating system.

Answer (score 0):

You should unlock the disk before doing that.

First, Log out

Then, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

The tty terminal will be shown.

Stop display manager's service by typing (Ubuntu 15.10 and later)

```
sudo systemctl stop lightdm
```

or

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

Go to / (root directory) and umount /home directory by typing

```
cd /
sudo umount -f /home
```

Start again lightdm service by typing

```
sudo systemctl start lightdm
```

The session login screen will be shown. Login and proceed resizing the disk with gparted or any tool you wish.

Your user's data will not be accessible, you've unmounted your `/home` directory.

After resizing you can mount manually by doing the an similar process. Or you can just reboot. Mount rules in `/etc/fstab` will be followed by default and you are be able to access your data again in your `/dev/sda5` resized and automatically mounted in `/home`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't resize a non-free partition, it will take a very long time and probably get stuck at some point.

My sugestion:

a) clone/copy this partition somewhere for backup purpose, maybe with clonezilla itself, cp command.

b) better do it on a desktop machine, they're usually more stable, handle heat better on low level operations.

c) reinstall ubuntu and set home partition EXACTLY the same size of backed up one.

d) overwrite the just installed home partition with the backed up one.

obs: note that user/password should be the same on both backed up/reinstalled partition to avoid more trouble.

if everything goes fine you should have an equal home partition and a lot of settings already done.